# R zip stop printing of "updating ..."

Tags: r, zip

I use the zip command to zip up a long list of files. The default output to the console for the processing includes a new line for every file added to the archive.

Here's the line of code I use.

```
zip(zipfile = "zipOut.zip", files = list.files(path = "graphics"))
```

How can I turn the updating messages off?

Comment: Maybe also `suppressMessages(zip(zipfile = "zipOut.zip", files = list.files(path = "graphics")))`.

Comment: Tried that. It doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After browsing around I found that adding an `extras` option did the trick.

```
zip(zipfile = "zipOut.zip", files = list.files(path = "graphics"), extras = "-qdgds 10m")
```

This replaces the messages with a line of dots with each dots equal to 10 MB. Other options are available at https://linux.die.net/man/1/zip